# Firefox redirect section bug

Tags: html, firefox, web, firebug

I'm trying to redirect to my price section of my webiste by the following link: https://www.paydomestic.com.br/#pricing

```
<a href="https://www.paydomestic.com.br/#pricing"></a>
```

Google chrome works correctly, already in firefox does not work.

but this only occurs via link, if you put the url "https://www.paydomestic.com.br/#pricing" and press enter in the browser works, but not via link!

why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

```
<script>
/*location.hash returns the anchor part of an URL as a string, 
with hash (#) symbol included. */
//wait for page elements to load
//execute function only if the anchor exists in the URL address
window.onload = function() {if(location.hash){
    //remove # from the string
    var elId = location.hash.replace('#','');
    //locate the anchored element on the page by its ID property 
    var scrollToEl = document.getElementById(elId);
    //scroll to the anchored element
    scrollToEl.scrollIntoView(true);   
}
 }
</script>
```